# Get intersection range of two non-discrete intervals

Tags: python, intervals

Given an interval defined by a start and end point (both floats), I would like to determine the intersection range with a second interval. For example:

```
int1 = [2. , 5.] 
int2 = [2.2, 7.]

>>> desired_function(int1, int2)
2.8
```

It should handle all intersection possibilities (no intersection, partial intersection, complete intersection, also negative ranges etc.). My attempt looks like this:

```
def intersection(int1, int2):

    #case 1: partial intersection over the left or right border
    if (int2[0]<=int1[0] and int2[1]<=int1[1]) or (int2[0]>=int1[0] and int2[1]>=int1[1]):
        return min(int1[1],int2[1]) - max(int1[0],int2[0])

    #case 2: complete overlap of one interval by the other
    elif (int2[0]>=int1[0] and int2[1]<=int1[1]) or (int2[0]<=int1[0] and int2[1]>=int1[1]):
        return min (int2[1]-int2[0] , int1[1]-int1[0])

    #case 3: no overlap at all
    else:
        return 0
```

Question: Have I missed something and is there any build-in solution or package that does something similar since want to keep my code as simple and fast as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making things too complicated, a simple function to do this is:

```
def interval_intersect(a,b):
    a0,a1 = a
    b0,b1 = b
    return max(0,min(a1,b1)-max(a0,b0))
```

We simply calculate the maximum of the start of the two intervals and the minimum of the end between these intervals. We then calculate the difference and use `max(0,...)` to make sure that if there is no interval, we will return 0.

We can generalize the function further into:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def interval_intersect(*args):
    return max(0,min(map(itemgetter(1),args))-max(map(itemgetter(0),args)))
```

to let it work with an arbitrary number of intervals. These both give:

```
>>> interval_intersect((2,5),(2.2,7))
2.8
```

Comment: Thanks! This is actually exactly the `return` statement of my first case, however I was somehow trying to hard and did not realize that this already handles all possibilities... `+1` for the solution for multiple intervals

Answer (score 2):

You could do this,

`max(0, min(range1[1], range2[1]) - max(range1[0], range2[0]))`